# Store and extract specific data from serial

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

```
if(mySerial.available()){
    size_t len = mySerial.available();
    uint8_t sbuf[len];
    mySerial.readBytes(sbuf, len);
    //push UART data to all connected telnet clients
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++){
      if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()){
        serverClients[i].write(sbuf, len);
        delay(1);
```

I am receiving data from UART port with this code, and sending directly to telnet clients. Since I am receiving a Modbus hex code:

```
10 03 02 01 1F 04 1F
```

> I need to extract 4th and 5th pair 011F and send only that as a
>   decimal number to TCP.

I get it that I have to store it to a string or an array? And then extract data from that, but since I have no common end of line breaks and my numbers change (but keep the format).
I have no idea where to start. I tried to find online but I am simply stuck and am in need of an assistance.

Can someone direct me on where to look or form a code for this and try to explain the logic on what he did.

Since I am doing this on ESP8266 I am trying to keep it simple.

Comment: If you want `01` `1F` to go to `011F`, say `int x = (sbuf[3] << 8) | sbuf[4];` and, hey presto, you'll have 287 (which is `0x011F`) in `x`.  That's a "big endian" representation.  If it's actually supposed to be little endian, you could use `x = sbuf[3] | (sbuf[4] << 8)` and get 7937.

Comment: The modbus documentation explains the protocol. I would start with that. You haven't explained what your requirements so it's impossible for us to guide you to a robust solution

Comment: Thanks Steve, that was exactly what i was looking for. But this code just gives me one buffered data. Specifically the fourth one and third was nowhere displayed.